# Installing Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install RoR on my ubuntu 12.04 (32bit) i am following the instructions found on this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm  ; all goes well i even create a project run bundle install and after that i was able to startup using rails server . The problem is when i turnoff my machine and reboot and cd into the same directory and issue the command rails or bundle the ubuntu can't find them and asks me to install them using apt!!! what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using rvm. You probably didn't set the Ruby env used by rails as the default.

Run:

```
rvm list
```

This will display the available rubies on your machine (under rvm control).

Run:

```
rvm use <ruby used by rails>
```

That should load your rails environment.

Comment: Please up vote the answer. It fixed your problem right?